# Upgraded to 4.6.2 - 'New Mailing' brings up 'Unknown Extension' error

Tags: civimail, 4.6.2

Just upgraded CiviCRM from 4.5.3 to 4.6.2 on Wordpress. All seems to be working apart from when I select 'New Mailing' option under 'Mailings' - it takes me to a screen showing the message below:

*Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.

Unknown extension: .

Return to home page.*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get a more complete error message if you turn on debug + backtrace in CiviCRM. Also, since the message is coming from the extensions system, can you try disabling your CiviCRM extensions?

Comment: Problem solved, it was a Gift Aid extension not working properly. I disabled it and now the New Mailing option works. Thanks for your help :)